# Getting transactions history for account

Tags: transactions, horizon

I am trying to monitor the transactions for our main account. I am using the laboratory and I see something weird..
I filter it with ascending order to see from start up to now.
My question is: From all the records that I see under this cursor - are they the previous records? And if yes, how do I get the first cursor that has no prev paging_token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursor is optional and if you simply leave it blank then you'll get the first page containing the very first (if ascending) or very last (if descending) transactions. Indeed you'll allways get a prev link but if you follow it you'll also see that it returns an empty result.